# Get WAN ip by sockaddr_in

Tags: c, sockets, wan

I'm trying to get client's ip by my sockaddr_in but this ip always 192.168.1.1(router ip).How can i get WAN ip correctly?

Comment: Who is connecting to whom ? Show some code.

Comment: My client program connects to my my server program.
'accept( listener ,(sockaddr * ) &infos , &size);
ip=inet_ntoa(infos.sin_addr);'

Comment: Where is the client and where is the server ? (nat, internet) You shouldn't normally get `192.168.1.1`.

Comment: In internet. I opened my port. The clients can connect me by my internet ip adress.

Comment: If you mentioned "I opened my port" then you're likely behind the NAT.

Comment: Yes, i am behind the NAT.

Comment: @AtakanErbaş This is impossible. You cannot, in any way, get the IP address of a NAT gateway that's between your machine and the peer from an sockaddr_in. You'd have to get that info from somewhere else, either someone manually providing it to your program, or you'll have to come up with a protocol where the clients send you the internet IP they're connecting to.

Comment: @nos: Why not post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you have some kind of reverse proxy running on the router. It may have added the client IP somewhere e.g. as an X-Forwarded-For header for HTTP.